# Figuring out the Volume of Revolution and avoiding $u$-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this question.

> Calculate the volume of revolution when V is revolved around the x-axis. Give an exact answer.
>
> $f(x)=\frac{2e^x}{1+e^x}$
>
> The area V is enclosed by the graph of $f(x)$ and lines $x=2$ and $y=1$

I know we should integrate the function this way to find the volume when the graph is revolved around the x-axis:
$$\pi\int_?^? f(x)^2dx$$

But well, first of all, I'm not sure which $x$ intervals are meant here. I only have the one $x=2$.

Secondly, I did not learn $u$ substitution, not really sure how I'm supposed to integrate $\frac{2e^x}{1+e^x}$ (which is what we are supposed to do without $u$-substitution).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: note that the formula for the volume is $\pi\int [f(x)]^2dx$

Comment: Not sure where my math would be without you correcting my stupid mistakes, probably somewhere trying to figure out why solving my fractions didn't work ^^ as always thanks gimusi

Comment: Recognize our mistakes is a good wat to learn! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- make a sketch of $f(x)$ which is an increasing funtion which is $<1$ for $x<0$
- then with the given data the set up should be

$$\pi\int_{-\infty}^0 [f(x)]^2\,dx+\pi\int_{0}^2 1^2\,dx$$